# undefined indexedDB on Windows Phone 8.1 javascript app

Tags: javascript, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, indexeddb

I have the following code on a (HTML/javascript) Windows Store app

```
var reqOpen = window.indexedDB.open(that.dbName, that.dbVersion);
```

The thing is, when I wanted to use that exact code on a (HTML/javascript) Windows Phone 8.1 app I get `undefined` on `window.indexedDB`.

I can't seem to find any samples or anything related to indexedDB on WinPhone. The only article that I found that mentions both Windows Store and Windows Phone apps is [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553412.aspx), but it is not clear if there's a difference for either 'platform'

Am I missing something?

Comment: http://imgur.com/A22AfN9

Comment: I got the same problem when following tutorial at  http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2012/07/10/creating-an-indexeddbdatasource-for-winjs and from the article's title `indexeddbdatasource-for-winjs` implied that it is available for WP8.1 but not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IndexedDB is not available on Windows Phone 8.1 HTML store apps.

I wrote a [SQLite for Windows Apps blog post](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/07/02/writing-a-sqlite-wrapper-component-for-universal-windows-apps/) which mentions this and describes how you might work around it: wrap up SQLite in WinRT and use that instead.

The blog post is mostly about creating your own but it also links to some existing projects that do this and that might have acceptable licenses for you, including [SQLite-WinRT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ukmsdn/archive/2013/06/06/sqlite-winrt-database-programming-on-windows-phone-and-windows-8.aspx).

SQLite isn't necessarily your only option, but it is the only one I know of that is popular, has written VS extensions, and is actively supporting running in Windows store apps.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider adding quotes from the links to your answer, so link rot may not make the answer obsolete in the future.

Comment: Thanks, I guess there are a couple od documentation bugs where they talk about IndexedDB with the little phone icon. Is SQLite my only alternative for wp database access?

Comment: Having spent a long time trying to get various database options to work in Wp8.1/10, I can say Dave Risney's sample is the only one which works for me. Cloudcrypt has a version on github based on this, that also works. [https://github.com/cloudcrypt/SQLite-Universal-WinJS-Component]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the prefixed global described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441274.aspx)? Something like the following preceding the call to window.indexedDB.open: `window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;`.

Comment: yes I have... and I get the same thing: `undefined` :(