# Is indexedDB available on Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8, winjs, indexeddb

Maybe a weird question as you would probably say, just Google it but I can't find a clear statement. When I do window.indexedDB or windows.msIndexedDB I get an undefined error. That would imply it's not available.

However, when I look at this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553412.aspx I get the feeling it should be available. Also when I check here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage it says that indexedDB is available on Windows Phone 8 (no mention of 8.1 though). So it seems to be supported or is it only supported when using PhoneGap? Or was it supported in version 8 and did they remove it in 8.1?

Comment: possible duplicate of [undefined indexedDB on Windows Phone 8.1 javascript app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25307897/undefined-indexeddb-on-windows-phone-8-1-javascript-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IndexedDB is not yet supported by Windows Phone 8.1, but there is a [cordova-plugin-indexeddb](https://github.com/msopentech/cordova-plugin-indexeddb)  shim based on [WebSql](https://github.com/msopentech/cordova-plugin-websql).

To install the plugin use
`cordova plugin add com.msopentech.indexeddb`

Answer (score 0):

Their [WebSQL plugin](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/cordova-plugin-websql) works well too. It seems to implement WebSQL pretty well. The only difference I've noticed so far is that they don't support the **readTransaction** method (only **transaction**).