# Phonegap IndexedDB shims for windows phone 8.1

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, indexeddb

I turns out that IndexedDB is not available on Windows Phone 8.1 HTML store apps.

See related question.   [undefined indexedDB on Windows Phone 8.1 javascript app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25307897/undefined-indexeddb-on-windows-phone-8-1-javascript-app)

A possible work around has been suggested to use the plugin
[msopentech plugin](https://github.com/msopentech/cordova-plugin-indexeddb)

Has anyone had any experience with this plugin and know of any gaps or issues with it.

So far we've been unable to get auto incrementing keys to work.

Are there any other viable shims people could suggest ?

Is there any timeline for when of if indexedDb is to be implemented on windows phone 8.1

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In the end I used [Microsoft's WebSQL plugin](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/cordova-plugin-websql). It's a little old school but it seems a little more straightforward. Their [IndexedDb solution](https://github.com/msopentech/cordova-plugin-indexeddb) might work OK but I figured it's a plugin, built on a shim ([IndexedDBShim](https://github.com/axemclion/IndexedDBShim)), built on *another* plugin (WebSQL) - it just seemed like there was too much going on (I preferred a more direct path to the database).